# How to prevent a user from modifying the value(using debugger option of any web browser) of a javascript variable bound to an html control?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html input control bound to a javascript variable. I would like to prevent any modification of the value by the user(from debug mode). It is actually a Total Price field. I would like this field to be computed by the javascript and not modifiable after that.

Comment: If you want the total price to be calculated on the user side and *not* be recalculated by the server, you are doing it wrong - there is no way to prevent that. You have to always expect that the user sends 0$ on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. On the frontend everything can be changed and should not be depended on to be valid. Values like a total cost of something should always be checked server side to make sure the frontend input was valid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

If you need to make the price secure then you need to process it on the back end.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on client side for those things. You need to have that value on your server.